# How to check empty array string before creating json object in java?

Tags: java, gson, classcastexception

I'm getting an empty array in string as a response from server & getting ClassCastException while converting it JsonObject because it's an empty array. Here is code snippet.

```
final String errorMessage = IOUtils.toString(errorStream); // response is "[]"
if (isJson(errorMessage)) {
  final JsonObject jsonResult = new Gson().fromJson(errorMessage, JsonObject.class);
        throw new IOException(jsonResult.get("error").toString());
} else {
    throw new IOException("Json response is" + errorMessage);
}
```

Here is isJson Method

```
public static boolean isJson(String Json) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(Json);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                new JSONArray(Json);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

should i add a check to compare "[]" like

```
if(isJson(errorMessage) && !errorMessage.equals("[]"))
```

or there could be any other better way to do it.

Please guide.

Thanks,

Comment: An empty json array should still be a json array ... if you get an exception can you provide the full stacktracke?

Comment: You shouldn't cast something which may be either an array or an object to `JsonObject`. You should cast it to `JsonElement` instead.

Comment: If you have java POJO corresponding to that response then you can use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to map json string to that object directly. I use that every time. Just a suggestion out of my experience. :)

Comment: Check by 
if(errorStream.length()==0){ 
// Do your work
}else{
// Do your work
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method from `is*` family:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

String[] jsons = {"[]", "[ ]", "[\r\n]", "{}", "{\"error\":\"Internal error\"}"};
for (String json : jsons) {
    JsonElement root = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
    if (root.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonElement error = root.getAsJsonObject().get("error");
        System.out.println(error);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
null
"Internal error"
```

There is no point to check `"[]"` string because between brackets could be many different white characters. `JsonElement` is a root type for all `JSON` objects and is safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!errorMessage[0]==null)
```

If your array is empty at position 0, it is returned null, or if you declare the array size when you declare it to be done:

```
 if(!errorMessage[0]=="")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it