# Parsing JSON data using GSON api

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON data and able to get the JSON data into a string.

I wish to get a json array from the root object one by one (using a loop if many are there)

The returned object must be of type "**com.google.gson.JsonObject**" as another method takes this object as input to get me the attribute values.

my json looks like this:

I would be needing the json array in "**Resources**" -

```
{
    "totalResults": 2,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
    ],
    "Resources": [
        {
            "owner": {},
            "application": {
                "displayName": "Non Auth App",
                "value": "4028b88168fa3d38016900d1759405a6",
                "$ref": "http://localhost:8080/identityiq/scim/v2/Applications/4028b88168fa3d38016900d1759405a6"
            },
            "meta": {
                "created": "2019-03-22T18:40:30.505+05:30",
                "location": "http://localhost:8080/identityiq/scim/v2/Entitlements/297eff8a699f8b3a0169a5863769008b",
                "version": "W/\"1553260230505\"",
                "resourceType": "Entitlement"
            },
            "schemas": [
                "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:Entitlement"
            ],
            "displayableName": "reader",
            "aggregated": false,
            "id": "297eff8a699f8b3a0169a5863769008b",
            "requestable": true,
            "attribute": "Privileges",
            "type": "Entitlement",
            "descriptions": [],
            "value": "reader"
        },
        {
            "owner": {},
            "application": {
                "displayName": "Non Auth App",
                "value": "4028b88168fa3d38016900d1759405a6",
                "$ref": "http://localhost:8080/identityiq/scim/v2/Applications/4028b88168fa3d38016900d1759405a6"
            },
            "meta": {
                "created": "2019-03-18T19:11:47.912+05:30",
                "location": "http://localhost:8080/identityiq/scim/v2/Entitlements/297eff8a6990fc49016991096d08001e",
                "version": "W/\"1552916507912\"",
                "resourceType": "Entitlement"
            },
            "schemas": [
                "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:Entitlement"
            ],
            "displayableName": "admin",
            "aggregated": false,
            "id": "297eff8a6990fc49016991096d08001e",
            "requestable": true,
            "attribute": "Privileges",
            "type": "Entitlement",
            "descriptions": [],
            "value": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? If you do not need `POJO` class, deserialise `JSON` payload to `JsonElement` class. In your case you can even use `JsonObject` because root object is `JSON object`. See example from this question: [How to check empty array string before creating json object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335589/how-to-check-empty-array-string-before-creating-json-object-in-java/55335789#55335789)

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for your input!

Comment: I was able to get things done with

Comment: JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();   JsonArray results = object.get("Resources").getAsJsonArray();